# Tablayout inside another tablayout

Tags: android, material-design

Sir,I have a tablayout with 4 fragment.In one of those fragments i want one more tablayout to show furthur subpages but as soon as i initialise tablayout inside fragment it gives an exception.Is their any way to do so or any another alternative to meet my demands.

```
public class Fragment4 extends Fragment {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
// TextView textView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment4,container,false);

    tabLayout= (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout2);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pagers);
    ViewAdapter adapter = new            ViewAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    TabLayout.Tab news = tabLayout.newTab();
    TabLayout.Tab Chats = tabLayout.newTab();
    TabLayout.Tab Contacts = tabLayout.newTab();
    TabLayout.Tab Notes = tabLayout.newTab();
    news.setText("News Feed");
    Chats.setText("Chats");
    Contacts.setText("Contacts");
    Notes.setText("Notes");
    tabLayout.addTab(news, 0);
    tabLayout.addTab(Chats, 1);
    tabLayout.addTab(Contacts, 2);
    tabLayout.addTab(Notes, 3);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getActivity(), R.color.mdtp_button_color));
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent));
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    return v;


}


}
```

---

here is my stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.shivambhusri.fireapp, PID: 3543
     java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     at com.example.shivambhusri.fireapp.Fragment4.onCreateView(Fragment4.java:42)
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:164)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:608)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:570)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:551)
     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2008)
     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1025)
     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:995)
     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1272)
     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1377)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20329)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: Paste the code and stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to use this type of layout(tablayout inside a tablayout), since it will cause aesthetic and usability issues.

Comment: Is their any alternative to implement the same like using four buttons and providing them scrolling behaviour or something like that,